# extjs 3.3 grid grouping and sum

Tags: extjs

I want to write the sums of some data under grouping and grid. I am sharing my codes, I will be glad if you help. Thank you.

```
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
      url: 'ajaxQueryData?_qid=4146',
      root: 'data',
      totalProperty: 'browseInfo.totalCount',
      remoteSort: true,
      id: 'sira_no',
      sortInfo: {
        field: 'sira_no',
        direction: 'ASC'
      },

      fields: [

        {
          name: "sira_no",
          type: "int"
        },
        {
          name: "branch_id_qw_"
        },
        {
          name: "firma"
        },
        {
          name: "sevk_adres"
        },
        {
          name: "malzeme"
        },
        {
          name: "group_id_qw_"
        },
        {
          name: "kategori_id_qw_"
        },
        {
          name: "alt_kategori_id_qw_"
        },
        {
          name: "vade"
        },
        {
          name: "birim_tip_qw_"
        },
        {
          name: "miktar"
        },
        {
          name: "kg"
        },
        {
          name: "birim_fiyat"
        },
        {
          name: "para_birim_qw_"
        },
        {
          name: "net_tutar"
        },
        {
          name: "irsaliye_dt"
        },
        {
          name: "irsaliye_no"
        },
        {
          name: "fatura_dt"
        },
        {
          name: "fatura_no"
        },
        {
          name: "sehir_id_qw_"
        },
        {
          name: "ilce_id_qw_"
        },
        {
          name: "satis_sorumlusu_id_qw_"
        }
      ],
      pageSize: 50,
      autoLoad: {
        params: {
          startRow: 0,
          fetchCount: 50
        }
      }
      // proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({

      // })
    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
      store: store,
      columns: [{
          id: 'sira_no',
          header: 'Sıra No',
          width: 50,
          sortable: true,
          dataIndex: 'sira_no'
        },
        {
          header: 'Şube',
          width: 150,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'branch_id_qw_'
        },
        {
          header: 'Firma',
          width: 250,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'firma'
        },
        {
          header: 'Sevk Adresi',
          width: 150,
          sortable: true,
          hidden: true,
          dataIndex: 'sevk_adres'
        },
        {
          header: 'Malzeme Adı',
          width: 200,
          sortable: true,
          hidden: true,
          dataIndex: 'malzeme'
        },
        {
          header: 'Grup',
          width: 100,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'group_id_qw_'
        },
        {
          header: 'Kategori',
          width: 100,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'kategori_id_qw_'
        },
        {
          header: 'Alt Kategori',
          width: 100,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'alt_kategori_id_qw_'
        },
        {
          header: 'Vade (gün)',
          width: 80,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'vade'
        },
        {
          header: 'Birim',
          width: 50,
          sortable: true,
          hidden: true,
          dataIndex: 'birim_tip_qw_'
        },
        {
          header: 'Miktar',
          width: 80,
          sortable: true,
          hidden: true,
          dataIndex: 'miktar'
        },
        {
          header: 'Kg',
          width: 80,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'kg'
        },
        {
          header: 'Birim Fiyat',
          width: 80,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'birim_fiyat'
        },
        {
          header: 'Para Birimi',
          width: 50,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'para_birim_qw_'
        },
        {
          header: 'Net Tutar',
          width: 80,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'net_tutar'
        },
        {
          header: 'İrsaliye Tarihi',
          width: 100,
          sortable: true,
          hidden: true,
          dataIndex: 'irsaliye_dt'
        },
        {
          header: 'İrsaliye No',
          width: 100,
          sortable: true,
          hidden: true,
          dataIndex: 'irsaliye_no'
        },
        {
          header: 'Fatura Tarihi',
          width: 100,
          sortable: true,
          hidden: true,
          dataIndex: 'fatura_dt'
        },
        {
          header: 'Fatura No',
          width: 100,
          sortable: true,
          hidden: true,
          dataIndex: 'fatura_no'
        },
        {
          header: 'Şehir',
          width: 120,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'sehir_id_qw_'
        },
        {
          header: 'İlçe',
          width: 120,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'ilce_id_qw_'
        },
        {
          header: 'Satış Sorumlusu',
          width: 200,
          sortable: true,

          dataIndex: 'satis_sorumlusu_id_qw_'
        }
      ],
      viewConfig: {
        forcefit: true
      },
      //resizable: true,
      width: function() {
        $("#aciklama").width();
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".slide-left").click(function() {

            Width: $("#aciklama").width();
          })
          $(".slide-right").click(function() {

            Width: $("#aciklama").width() - 334;
          })
        })
      },
      height: $("#aciklama").height(),

      frame: true,

      tbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        pageSize: 50,
        store: store,

        displayInfo: true

      })
    });

    grid.render('aciklama');
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery in your ExtJs?

Comment: The rate doesn't matter much, I don't use it anyway.

Comment: May you provide https://fiddle.sencha.com/ sample?

Comment: @ArthurRubens https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3881

Comment: I mean fiddle sample with your grid.. working sample.